# Mac osx lion, virtualenv, pil install - gcc error

Tags: python, django, macos, python-imaging-library

I have just completed the xcode install, mac osx lion. Upon completion I attempted to install PIL in a virtual enviroment using pip, easy_install and home brew. All three are erring out. pip install give the following error:

pip `

```
unable to execute gcc-4.0: No such file or directory

error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

`

easy_install `unable to execute gcc-4.0: No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1`

home brew `Error: Failed executing: python setup.py build_ext`

I am not really sure where to go from here.

Thanks,
CG

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Xcode 4.1 on OS X Lion 10.7 no longer includes `gcc-4.0` as it did in earlier versions of OS X.  When you install a Python package like PIL that includes a C extension module, Python's Distutils will attempt to use the same version of the C compiler that that Python itself was build with.  It sounds like the version of Python that was used to create your `virtualenv` is an older 32-bit-only Python built with `gcc-4.0`.  You can tell for sure by starting the `python` in your `virtualenv`.  If it says `gcc-4.0`, you will need to re-create the virtualenv, using a newer base Python, either one of the Apple-supplied Pythons in Lion or installing a newer python using a python.org installer or a brew recipe.  Then install `Distribute` and `pip` and `virtualenv` for that Python, create a new virutalenv and then install PIL in it.

Comment: Here is what it say in the description line of python: Python 2.6.4 (r264:75821M, Oct 27 2009, 19:48:32) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin

Comment: Yes, that appears to be an old Python 2.6.4 from python.org.  You can see if it is installed in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6`.  You can uninstall it by typing: `sudo rm -r /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6` That's all on one line and type carefully!

Comment: Awesome, I just got everything up and running. Your are amazing!

Comment: For anyone still fighting with this one, i posted the solution that worked for me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832294/pil-installation-fails-missingstdarg-h/

Comment: For someone just looking to solve this problem, this answer beats around the bush a lot. I don't know how to solve the issue after reading the answer.

Comment: korona: Rather than down-voting an answer that apparently has been found useful by others, perhaps you might consider asking your own question or being more explicit about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

After spending hours on the same problem this is what it worked for me:

Download the PIL source code and cd into it.
Check which version of `gcc` do you have by:

```
gcc
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: no input files
```

Then I force to apply this version by:

```
export CC=gcc-4.2
```

And select the correct architecture (in my case 32bit):

```
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386"
```

For 64 use export `ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"`

Then build and install:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you find the `gcc-4.0` binary on your system?  You might need to add the directory it's in to your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: there is one in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.0  which seems rather random. There is not a copy in usr/bin or/developer/usr/bin which is what I would expect. How would I add that to my PATH env var?

Answer (score 0):

If it helps any, I solved this pesky issue with sym links, and I think it will work for you. I wrote this with my version of gcc in mind, which is 4.2:

```
cd /usr/bin
rm cc gcc c++ g++
ln -s gcc-4.2 cc
ln -s gcc-4.2 gcc
ln -s c++-4.2 c++
ln -s g++-4.2 g++
ln -s gcc-4.2 gcc-4.0
```

There ya go!

Answer (score 0):

An Idea would be to point gcc-4.0 to the default gcc flag:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.0
```