# GCC error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, macos, gcc, xcode4, fabric

I am trying to install Fabric into a Virtualenv / Django 1.3.1 / OS X Lion with Xcode 4.2. This error seems to be [fairly prevalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906385/mac-osx-lion-virtualenv-pil-install-gcc-error) but I can't seem to find an answer when you are running Python 2.7 & Xcode 4.2.

I'm running:

Python 2.7 (r27:82508, Jul  3 2010, 21:12:11) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)]

How do I execute gcc-4.0 instead of gcc-4.0.1?

Thanks!

The full Fabric install + error:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): fabric in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages/Fabric-0.1.0-py2.7.egg
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): paramiko>=1.7,<2.0 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko-1.7.7.1-py2.7.egg (from fabric)
Downloading/unpacking pycrypto>=2.1 (from paramiko>=1.7,<2.0->fabric)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pycrypto

Installing collected packages: pycrypto
  Running setup.py install for pycrypto
    warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
    building 'Crypto.Hash.MD2' extension
    gcc-4.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64 -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/src/MD2.o
    unable to execute gcc-4.0: No such file or directory
    error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /Users/emilepetrone/Sites/newsite/salesapp/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/emilepetrone/Sites/newsite/salesapp/build/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /var/folders/hv/yjvyz6g96xd4c4nbg3hgtk9c0000gn/T/pip-R0wRzk-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /Users/emilepetrone/Sites/newsite/salesapp/bin/../include/site/python2.7:
    running install

running build

running build_configure

running build_py

running build_ext

warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.

building 'Crypto.Hash.MD2' extension

gcc-4.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64 -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/src/MD2.o

unable to execute gcc-4.0: No such file or directory

error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Same issue with OSX 10.7. My fix:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -s gcc gcc-4.0
```

the version of MySQL-python I downloaded called for gcc-4.0
gcc is already a symlink to the apple gcc build.

P.S. Make sure you have xcode and command line tools installed as well

Comment: Shouldn't this be `sudo ln -s gcc gcc-4.0`?

Answer (score 0):

strange, I'm still on the OS X snow leopard, when I type gcc-4.0 I get:

```
 i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.0.1: no input files
```

so I guess the actual implementation version is 4.0.1 but the executable name is gcc-4.0

maybe you should try creating a link gcc-4.0 that will point to your executable (4.0.1)

Comment: I have a 10.8.2 box here, and it does not behave that way.  But, I have 4.2.1 running with the latest Xcode currently.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps any, I solved this pesky issue with sym links, and I think it will work for you. I wrote this with my version of gcc in mind, which is 4.2:

```
cd /usr/bin
rm cc gcc c++ g++
ln -s gcc-4.2 cc
ln -s gcc-4.2 gcc
ln -s c++-4.2 c++
ln -s g++-4.2 g++
ln -s gcc-4.2 gcc-4.0
```

There ya go!