# PIL Installation Fails missing:stdarg.h

Tags: python, linux, python-imaging-library, easy-install

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Python Imaging Library (PIL) on Snow Leopard with updated Python 2.6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438270/installing-python-imaging-library-pil-on-snow-leopard-with-updated-python-2-6)

Runing MAC 10.7.2 While trying to install PIL, after resolving many gcc issues, the installation exits with this line:

> /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error:
>   stdarg.h: No such file or directory

i'm using this line for install:

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" easy_install PIL
```

full output:

> WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated
>   package names in setup.py
>   --- using frameworks at /System/Library/Frameworks In file included from
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h:4,
>                    from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:85,
>                    from _imaging.c:75: /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error:
>   stdarg.h: No such file or directory
>   _imaging.c:3017: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
>   _imaging.c:3077: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type In file included from
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h:4,
>                    from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:85,
>                    from _imaging.c:75: /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error:
>   stdarg.h: No such file or directory
>   _imaging.c:3017: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
>   _imaging.c:3077: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of:
>   /var/folders/2l/nrkm12097b58kk8n9hrbtz840000gn/T//cckCPEox.out error:
>   Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit
>   status 1

Comment: I'm afraid none of that helps me. and there is an update from may 2011, that states that the solution wont work for 10.7. i also noticed people reporting this issue from the last few days...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem Solved , the steps i took:

**Step 1:** Uninstalled and Installed Xcode, suggested here:
http://binarylionstudios.com/blog/2011/01/30/error-stdarg.h-no-such-file-or-directory/

to remove Xcode properlly follow this answer:
[How to fully remove Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255959/how-to-fully-remove-xcode-4)

> sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all

use the install Xcode.app after you restart your mac

**Step 2:** after xcode was reinstalled, the installation failed

> unable to execute gcc-4.2: No such file or directory PIL

to resolve that i followed this post:
http://aravir-rose.blogspot.com/2011/12/installing-python-27s-imaging-library.html

Good luck!